# Cordova error building on android platform: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, cordova, npm

I'm using cordova and android manager studio. 
Whenever I try the following, I get errors:

```
cordova emulate android
```

or

```
cordova run android
```

Whereas the same application works fine on browser.

So far, I've tried removing and adding the android platform back again (as it was recommended on the majority of posts I read) to no avail.

It throws the following error:

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 1.871 secs
>   Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c "C:\Users\Me\myFirstApp\platforms\android\gradlew.bat cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\Me\myFirstApp\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
>   Built the following apk(s):
>           C:/Users/Me/myFirstApp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
>   No scripts found for hook "before_deploy".
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
>   Running command: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   Command finished with error code 0: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat list avds""
>   Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat list avds"
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Me\myFirstApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)

Some information that may be helpful:

- Windows 10 pro x64
- Cordova 6.5.0
- Node v7.8.0
- Java JDK 1.8.0_121
- Environment variables on path:

  > C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk;C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: do you have android emulator installed previously or have successfully built any ionic app previously ?

Comment: if that is the case then go to https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html download the sdk tools for windows unzip it and paste it here `C:\Users\[YOU USER NAME]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools` and it will work