# ionic run failed with error - Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "D:\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat list avds"

Tags: android, ionic-framework

ionic run --verbose --target=Nexus9 -l -c -s

The above command fails with the following log.

LOG> Running command: D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices 
LOG> Command finished with error code 0: D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
LOG> Running command: D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
LOG> Command finished with error code 0: D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
LOG> Running command: cmd "/s /c "D:\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat list avds""
LOG> Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "D:\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat list avds"
LOG> ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

From the Error Log, I can see that it fails at the command "D:\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat list avds".

When I run this command  "android.bat list avds"  manually, I get the following error msg

LOG> Invalid or unsupported command "list avds" 
LOG> Supported commands are: 
LOG> android list target 
LOG> android list avd 
LOG> android list device

So, When I run the command "android.bat list avd" (removing s from avds), it runs successfully and returns me the list of avds.

But I'm confused why ionic run command, uses the command "D:\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat list avds" instead of "D:\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat list avd" and fails.

BTW, I'm using ionic 1.7.16 on windows 7 - 64 bit

Any advice is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

There are similar questions in this forum, but  without any answer, so, I asked this question. 
1. [Cordova error building on android platform: Command failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325686/cordova-error-building-on-android-platform-command-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on
[Cordova error running on android emulator: "android: Command failed with exit code 2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354800/cordova-error-running-on-android-emulator-android-command-failed-with-exit-co)

The new version of Android SDK is not compatible with cordova emulation.

So to solve this, inside the `platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js` replace:

```
return superspawn.spawn('android', ['list', 'avds'])
```

to

```
return superspawn.spawn('android', ['list', 'avd'])
```

Thanks to Douglas Neves